# Vue: Prop Value change not updating DOM

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

I have a child component

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="item-template">
  <li>
    <div
      class="item"
      :class="{active: selected}"
      @click="toggle">
      <span :style="margin">
        <i v-if="isFolder && !isOpen" class="fas fa-folder"></i>
        <i v-if="isFolder && isOpen" class="fas fa-folder-open"></i>
        <i v-if="!isFolder" class="fas fa-file"></i>
        {{ item.name }}
      </span>
      <b-dropdown no-caret>
        <template #button-content>
          <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </template>
        <b-dropdown-item v-if="isFolder" @click="$emit('show-add-file-modal', item.path)"><i class="fas fa-file-medical pr-1"></i> New File</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item v-if="isFolder" href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-upload pr-1"></i> Upload File</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item v-if="isFolder" @click="$emit('show-add-directory-modal', item.path)"><i class="fas fa-folder-plus pr-1"></i> New Directory</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-divider v-if="isFolder"></b-dropdown-divider>
        <b-dropdown-item @click="$emit('rename-item', item)"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt pr-1"></i> Rename</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item @click="$emit('delete-item', item)"><i class="fas fa-trash pr-1"></i> Delete</b-dropdown-item>
      </b-dropdown>
    </div>
    
    <ul v-show="isOpen" v-if="isFolder">
      <tree-item
        v-for="(child, index) in item.children"
        :key="index"
        :item="child"
        :tree-data-ui-helpers="treeDataUiHelpers"
        @set-active="$emit('set-active', $event)"
        @show-add-file-modal="$emit('show-add-file-modal', $event)"
        @show-add-directory-modal="$emit('show-add-directory-modal', $event)"
        @rename-item="$emit('rename-item', $event)"
        @delete-item="$emit('delete-item', $event)"
      ></tree-item>
    </ul>
  </li>
</script>

<script>
  Vue.component("tree-item", {
    template: "#item-template",
    props: {
      item: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
      },
      treeDataUiHelpers: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
      }
    },
    data: function() {
      return {
        isOpen: false,
        isSelected: false
      };
    },
    computed: {
      treeDataUiHelpersComputed: function() {
        console.log(this.treeDataUiHelpers);
        return this.treeDataUiHelpers;
      },
      isFolder: function() {
        return this.item.type === 'DIRECTORY';
      },
      margin: function() {
        return {"margin-left": (this.treeDataUiHelpers[this.item.path].level * 16) + 'px'};
      },
      selected: function() {
        console.log(this.treeDataUiHelpersComputed[this.item.path].selected);
        return this.treeDataUiHelpersComputed[this.item.path].selected
      },
    },
    watch: {
      treeDataUiHelpers: {
        handler(value) {
          console.log(value);
        },
        deep: true
      },
    },
    methods: {
      toggle: function() {
        if (this.isFolder) {
          this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
        }
        else {
          this.$emit("set-active", this.item);
        }
      },
    }
  });
</script>
```

Than i use this component as following in the parent component

```
<tree-item
  :item="treeData"
  :tree-data-ui-helpers="treeDataUiHelpers"
  @set-active="setActive"
  @show-add-file-modal="showAddFileModal"
  @show-add-directory-modal="showAddDirectoryModal"
  @rename-item="renameItem"
  @delete-item="deleteItem"
></tree-item>
```

Than i am changing the value of `treeDataUiHelpers` whenever i need to select the active item like this in the event handler

```
setActive: function(item) {
        if(!item) {
          this.setAllInActive();
          return;
        }
        const helperItem = this.treeDataUiHelpers[item.path];
        if(!helperItem.selected){              
          this.setAllInActive();
          //helperItem.selected = true; // not working
          //this.treeDataUiHelpers[item.path] = {...this.treeDataUiHelpers[item.path], selected:true};// not working
          Vue.set(this.treeDataUiHelpers[item.path], 'selected' , true); //not working
          //this.treeDataUiHelpers[item.path]= Object.assign({}, this.treeDataUiHelpers[item.path], {selected:true})// Not working
          console.log(this.treeDataUiHelpers[item.path]);
          this.setOpenedFilesActive( item.name, item.path);
          const contentItem = this.treeDataContent[item.path];
          const model = this.monaco.editor.createModel(
            contentItem.content,
            contentItem.type
          );
          this.editor.setModel(model);
        }
      },
```

Now, I have spent hours looking on stackoverflow and vue js forums and tried every solution there was. But i cannot get the dom to update when i change value of `treeDataUiHelpers`. Plus the watch for `treeDataUiHelpers` is also never firing no matter in which way i change the value of it in the parent. Any help would be appreciated.

PS, i can see in the dev tools that value is updated in the prop but dom is not updating and also computed values are not updating too.

Comment: Are these UI helpers used for display common toolbar icons on the tree? like edit, delete etc?

Comment: For now these are just for showing the level of the item in the tree and switching the active class of a tree item. I just don't want to mess up the object sent by the api so i created a helper object along with it for ui.

Comment: Is there a git repo somewhere?

Comment: No not possible for it,.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Props are immutable or you can say it has one-way data flow.

The one solution to this could be to subscribe to an event in treeItem component and then emit that event on treeDataUiHelpers change.

```
Vue.component("tree-item", {
    ...
created(){ 
      EventBus.$on('data-ui-helper-change', updatedTreeDataUiHelpers => {
      this.treeDataUiHelpers = updatedTreeDataUiHelpers 
  } ) 
},
data(){ return { treeDataUiHelpers = null } }
....
```

EventBus is a global, something like

```
EventBus = new Vue({});
```

But if you have more scenario like this then prefer Vuex for data sharing between the components.

Comment: But why do i have to use an event bus for that. Props are immutable from a child component and there is nothing wrong in mutating them from the owner i.e the parent.

Comment: My simple question is that props are reactive its very clearly stated everywhere, So why aren't computed values being recalculated when parent change an attribute in the prop object. Plus why isn't the watch function being triggered on change.

Comment: You got it wrong read this, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: No you are not understanding it correctly.  i do not want to change the data from child. I want to change the data from the parent and make sure it updates the dom on the data change. i understand data flows down but that's not the issue here, Issue is reactivity.

Comment: Oh, misunderstood it :(. just scrolled and found  // not working comments.

Answer (score 0):

If tried to replicate the situation and applied a double $set in setActive():
In my example (which I can supply on request) i start out with an empty treeDataUiHelpers object to proof that the double-set is effective. The selected property will be detected by all the tree-item nodes.

```js
setActive(item) { 
    this.$set(this.treeDataUiHelpers, item.path, this.treeDataUiHelpers[item.path] || {});
    this.$set(this.treeDataUiHelpers[item.path], 'selected', true);
}
```

If I look at your setActive function I see you try to do

```
if(helperItem.selected) {
     ...
     // various attempts to set treeDataUiHelpers selected to true
     ..
     Vue.set(this.treeDataUiHelpers[item.path], 'selected' , true); //not working
}
```

Which seems odd, if helperItem.selected is true-ish, try to set it to true?

Comment: Sorry the line actually is `if(!helperItem.selected)`. I will update the question

Comment: " i start out with an empty treeDataUiHelpers object to proof that the double-set is effective" Reagrding this. i do not need to proof that because i am sure that the object is there because i add levels of node on created hook which creates the objects

Comment: Allright, this seems like a problem that is hard to resolve remotely. Maybe you could provide more context about the parent component or provide a working example (jsfiddle, codesandbox, etc) that the code isn't working.

Comment: Ok i will try to put together a fiddle for it. maybe it cna shed light in a better way